# Anti aliasing of background image in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer, antialiasing

I have an image which is used as a background image. There is scaling done so the image appear jagged under Internet Explorer. How can I apply anti aliasing for a background image? Is it possible at all?

The code is not mine so the 'Don't scale images' is not a solution.

Comment: I'm not sure if works `-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;`

Comment: Unfortunately, @GermanoPlebani, I don't think that works anymore in newer versions of IE. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e800cbaf-a539-43ba-b5f9-1d29fe709ddc/the-awful-internet-explorer-image-renderengine?forum=ieitprocurrentver

Comment: Yes, it is not supported in the newer versions of IE.